# Binding a dataset column to a dropdownlist with Asp.net application

Tags: .net, vb.net, binding, ado.net, dataset

I used a `DataSet` with a column `Ref`, I'm trying to bind the values of this column to a dropdownlist

```
DropDownRef.DataSource = From r In liste.Tables(0).Columns("Ref") Select r
            DropDownRef.DataBind()
```

But it didn't work :(

1. So, how can I modify my snippet to do this task?
2. Is there another idea to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `DataColumn` as datasource. You need to use the data.

```
DropDownRef.DataSource = From r In liste.Tables(0).AsEnumerable()
                         Select r.Field(Of String)("Ref")
```